# nginx proxy_pass keep original uri

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have an outward facing server `out` with a domain e.g. `a.domain.com` and another server `internal` behind a firewall but reachable from `out`.

On Sever `out` I have a route configured as follows:

```
location /server/ {
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:80;
}
```

(the lines commented out are things I tried with no luck)

On Server `internal` I have:

```
location /db/ {
    proxy_pass http://db:port/;
}
```

When I try to access `https://a.domain.com/server` it displays the `404` from the `internal` nginx, working as expected.

Now if I try `https://a.domain.com/server/db/`. My device, in this case my phone (LTE), Gets redirected to `http://1.2.3.4/db`. That is obviously not reachable because it's behind a NAT and not a public IP.

What I want is that `https://a.domain.com/server/db/` is not redirected to `http://1.2.3.4/db` but stays `https://a.domain.com/server/db/`. So that the db is reachable through the `out` Server and its public domain. I'd call that cascading reverse proxy for lack of a better term.

I have tried these snippets I found in other stackoverflow topics

```
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: You could try: `proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:80/;`

Comment: Sadly that does not fix the problem. I still get redirected to `http://1.2.3.4/db/`

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be stripping the /server.
Not sure if you can try the below workaround:

```
location /server {
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4/server;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).